# Кaк вставить в матрицу нулей на случайные места целые числа без повторений?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Как вставить в матрицу нулей `matrix_zero` на случайные места все целые числа от 1 до N так, чтобы они не повторялись.

Пока написал вот такой код:

```
i = 1                                                                                                                                                
matrix_zero = np.zeros((5, 5))
 
print(matrix_zero)

N = # некое целое число 
while np.count_nonzero(matrix_zero) < N:
     
    matrix_zero[random.randint(0, 4)][random.randint(0, 4)] = i
    i += 1
```

Как его дополнить до правильного?

Comment: а что такое `aliens` ?

Comment: aliens - это список из словарей с характеристиками инопланетян, но в принципе уже неважно

Comment: Это важно, так как является важным уточнением вашего вопроса. Если вы уже получили желаемый ответ, то другие пользователи могут не понять вопрос, если будут искать решение подобной проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
k = 9 #len(aliens)
matrix_zero = np.zeros(n * n, dtype=np.int)
matrix_zero[:k] = range(1, k + 1)
np.random.shuffle(matrix_zero)
matrix_zero = matrix_zero.reshape((n, n))
print(matrix_zero)

[[0 9 4 0 0]
 [3 0 0 0 0]
 [0 7 0 6 0]
 [0 0 5 1 8]
 [0 0 2 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [42]: m = np.zeros((5, 5))

In [43]: N = 8

In [44]: m[np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(np.arange(np.prod(m.shape)), 
                                             size=N, 
                                             replace=False), 
                            m.shape)] = np.arange(1, N+1)
```

результат:

```
In [45]: m
Out[45]:
array([[0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 4., 0., 0., 6.],
       [0., 5., 0., 0., 1.],
       [3., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 8., 0., 0., 7.]])
```

Comment: Да, так эффективнее явно для больших матриц будет. Но выглядит непонятнее ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, согласен, что так менее понятно. Просто я хотел найти решение, которое будет вставлять значения в случайные места, не разрушая оригинальную матрицу. Т.е. если создать матрицу `m = np.arange(5 * 4).reshape(5, 4)` - то в результате я бы хотел изменить только случайно выбранные элементы, не затрагивая остальных

Comment: Да я понял, по сути решение правильнее моего, конечно )